# E500 error in payubiz integration , how to solve it?

Tags: payumoney

For our application we use payubiz as a payment gateway. While testing our app we are facing a new error [error code E500] Bank failed to authenticate the customer". I have no idea why this is happening for the past two weeks. Before that it worked very well. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have faced the same issue, rounding off the amount value solved it, `round(amount)`

Comment: @Ranjith Singhu, you are correct of course. After this issue we raised a ticket to the payubiz technical team and they responded that there exists a problem in their test server. So they suggested us to use rounded values as you said. Since then we use rounded values to test our app and payment goes successful. Anyway, Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you entered wrong card detail or use expired card.
Use fresh dummy card. It can be get from PayU for SANDBOX environment.

```
My dummy card detail as follows:
CardName: Any name
CardNumber: 5123456789012346 
CVV: 123
Expiry: May 2020
```