# PayU Biz E500 error code as Bank failed to authenticate the customer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payumoney

I'm testing my website which is integrated with PayU Money.  Weeks before the error, the code was working fine but now when I enter bank credentials and submit on the Test Server, it returns me an error code:

```
E500, "Unknown error pg"
```

The FormCollection Object says "Bank failed to authenticate the customer".

What can be the error that is getting this condition to occur?

Comment: Did you check the credentials?

Comment: Earlier it worked fine, but now it gives an E500 error

Comment: same happening with me.

Comment: @axcl please do inform me if you find the solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems you entered wrong card detail or use expired card. Use fresh dummy card. It can be get from PayU for SANDBOX environment.

```
My dummy card detail as follows:
CardName: Any name
CardNumber: 5123456789012346 
CVV: 123
Expiry: May 2020
```

[For more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611844/e500-error-in-payubiz-integration-how-to-solve-it/53829838#53829838)